# Error upgrading from 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, update-manager

While upgrading through "**Software Updater**", it faced with an error:

```
Could not install the package:
/tmp/apt-dpkg-install-JCuWPV/07-apparmor_2.13.3-7ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb package may not be in working state 
Please consider supporting a bug report.
new apparmor package pre-installation script subprocess returened error exit status 1
```

And it continued. The process ended with *could not install upgrade*.

```
The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unstable state. A recovery will run now (dpkg--configure-a)
```

After which it showed

> The upgrade is completed but there were errors during the upgrade process.

The system did not go through **cleaning up** and **restarting process** and everything aborted.

What to do now? Should I remove Apparmor package or what reinstall it or what?

Comment: An aborted release-upgrade is very bad. That "could be in an unstable state" warning is not kidding. Advice: Backup your data and reinstall a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, how? I had a reinstall of 16.04 , upgraded it to 18.04 and then finally to 20.04.. 
Now 20.04 aborted this way. How to reinstall a  newer release? I don't have another machine or device to help me. Jjust had a bootable 16.04 dvd

Comment: FYKI: It is possible to create a bootable USB for Ubuntu 20.04 (and probably newer releases as well; I haven't tested the newer releases myself) from your smartphone (preferably android) using the Etchdroid Application (3rd party but tested)

Comment: Another option is to ask a friend to make the LiveUSB on their machine.

Comment: @user535733 If I start again from 16.04 and try to upgrade, most probably I will face same issues again?

Comment: @Error404 okay I'll try it.

Comment: Note Ubuntu 18.04 has reached the end of its life and is not supported anymore. It's repositories may have been archived (I have not checked). [There is a question (and answers)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) about how to upgrade from an older version of Ubuntu in this site.

Comment: @user68186 yeah..just saw them :(

Comment: @Error404 Anyone any idea about the least size of pendrive that I should use to create a bootable USB? 4GB or 8GB?

Comment: @Spectra 8GB would be better. Although 4 GB should also work (depends on a variety of factors though, I recommend installing Xubuntu or Lubuntu (*which are official Ubuntu flavours*) if you dont have much space on the USB) I personally used a 64 GB flash drive.

Comment: @Error404 okay.. another question, you can format it and use it to make it bootable for other future versions, right? I think it should be, but still I want to make sure to avoid any blunders.

Comment: @Spectra yes, you can. The USB would be reusable once formatted.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here. I did:

```
apt --fix-broken install
apt autoremove
apt update && apt upgrade
```

And again:

```
apt --fix-broken install 
apt upgrade
```

Then it worked.